# Best method for printing on multiple printer by ASP.net webforms

Tags: asp.net

We are building a ASP.net web-form application.I would like to know what is the best possible method to solve this scenario. In one form we have 2 buttons to print. one is to print the invoice on a normal A4 printer attached to the client pc and with the 2nd button we need to print the bar-code on a label printer attached to the same client PC.We are using crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

Your UI is a browser.  You don't have access to any operating system APIs from the client-side code (JavaScript) that runs in the browser.  It would be a security risk if JavaScript had to ability to access and select a printer.  The only thing you can do with JavaScript is call the window.print() method which pops up a Print dialog box with the computer's default printer selected.

The only option I can think of is before calling window.print(), display a message telling them which printer they need to select.  But there's no guarantee that they even have that printer installed.